# datepicker, contextMenu popup on selecteddate

Tags: jquery, datepicker

When I select a date on datepicker want to popup a contextmenu. I have managed to add 
`$('#datepicker').addClass('context-menu-two box menu-1');` to datepicker itself, but cannot figure out how to do the same on 'a' or 'td' element of the datepicker. 
Any suggestion or code would be appreciated.

p.s. tried this too but not working

```
$(".ui-datepicker-current-day:eq(0)").siblings()
    .find('td a').addClass('context-menu-two box menu-1');
```

Comment: use your dev tools to see how datepicker relevant HTML is rendered

Comment: Ok. This is what firebug shows. I have Highlighted some specific dates. How do I get the 'a' element and change its class? <td class=" Highlighted ui-datepicker-current-day" data-year="2013" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" title="4733">
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">30</a>
</td>